# business logic in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, business-logic, business-layer

although i dont have much experience, but in terms of organization and logical thinking i am a big fan of putting bussiness logic just in BLL layer and against putting any business logic in stored procedures.

i am starting a new project now and not planning to put any business logic in stored procedures however i have some performance concerns, if i have some business operation that needs to check say 4 pieces of data from database while executing, if i made this operation as a stored procedure, i will visit database once, but if i made it in business layer i will have to visit database 4 times.

could this have an unforgivable implication on my application performance?

Comment: Have a read on [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and tell us your thoughts...

Comment: so you think i should not have these performance concerns?

Comment: At least not yet...but if performance is a concern see if a [designing for performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647781.aspx) can help.  Although that content is retired it's principles still hold today.